# How to identify if a user is launching a skill for the first time in Alexa without using a backend DB to store visit information?

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit

Is there any way we can identify if a user is launching a skill for the first time without using a backend DB to store visit information?

For example, the request object specifies if the user has granted a permission or not. Is there a way to also identify if a user is launching the skill for the first time?

```
{
   "version":"1.0",
   "session":{
      "new":true,
      "sessionId":"amzn1.echo-api.session.abc",
      "application":{
         "applicationId":"amzn1.ask.sabc3"
      },
      "user":{
         "userId":"amzn1.ask.account.AGQ"
      }
   },
   "context":{
      "System":{
         "application":{
            "applicationId":"amzn1.ask.skill.bb"
         },
         "user":{
            "userId":"amzn1.ask.account.AGQ"
         },
         "device":{
            "deviceId":"amzn1.ask.device.AHH",
            "supportedInterfaces":{

            }
         },
         "apiEndpoint":"https://api.amazonalexa.com",
         "apiAccessToken":"eysed"
      }
   },
   "request":{
      "type":"LaunchRequest",
      "requestId":"amzn1.echo-api.request.09b",
      "timestamp":"2018-10-15T17:03:03Z",
      "locale":"en-US",
      "shouldLinkResultBeReturned":false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid it is **not possible** to know if the user has launched the skill for very first time, without some storage mechanism like **Amazon S3**.

Yes, the request object tells you that if the user has provided permissions or not but it is not possible from the access token to know for sure that this user has used the skill for very first time.

Comment: I see, I see. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I had to go and add dynamoDB into the picture. The database storing the ***deviceId*** and the ***lastvisit*** timestamp.

Comment: Can you add additional links/code/flow as many of us are a newbie.

Answer (score -1):

You can identify by parallelly checking the following two conditions:

In request body, under session you will have **"new"** key. If it is **true** then the user is launching a skill for the first time.

```
{
      "version": "1.0",
      "session": {
        "new": true,
         .
         .
         .
}
```

Again in request body, under session there will be **"attributes"** key. It has to be **empty**.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.[unique-value-here]",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.[unique-value-here]"
    },
    "attributes": {
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I think this is not true. [docs here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#session-object) . session.new attribute and empty session.attributes just shows new session. Not a new user.